# Прослушивание событий курсора вне приложения Java

Tags: java

Мне нужно прослушивать события мыши вне моего приложения, а именно:

- Нажатие левой клавиши мыши (получение координат нажатия)
- Отпускание левой клавиши мыши
- Передвижение мыши (с точки, в которой была нажата левая клавиша мыши)

Подскажите, при помощи чего это можно реализовать? Побегав по форумам я смог найти только действия в пределах приложения (окна программы), но мне нужно получать значения в любой программе, в которой произошло изменение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если действовать можно только в пределах формы, то нужол сделать форму на весь экран(максимизхированную), но не fullScreen - контексты разные.
2. Дале, нужно как отлавливать события мыши, так и транслировать их дале - сквозь форму.

Поиски навели меня на решение на awt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190168/pass-mouse-events-to-applications-behind-from-a-java-ui

Далее - код из обсуждения по ссылке:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ClickThrough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Component c = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                g2.setColor(Color.gray);
                int w = getWidth();
                int h = getHeight();
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, w,h);
                g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
                g2.fillRect(w/4, h/4, w-2*(w/4), h-2*(h/4));
            }
        };
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        f.getContentPane().add(c);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(f,false);
    }

}
```

И примечание оттуда же: нужно использовать недекорированное окно (без панели состояния, кнопок максимизации/минимизации и прочего), иначе не будет работать.

С JavaFX пока пробую повторить такое же. Получится - дополню ответ.

Comment: Возникла проблема: прозрачная часть окна никак не обрабатывает события `MouseListener` и `MouseMotionListener`. Только видимая (серая форма).

Comment: Создам дополнительный вопрос, где будем решать проблему с пропусканием событий.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530578/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-jframe-java